# How do you update a user in Firebase using AngularFire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I can easily use this to create a user:

```
this.af.auth.createUser({email: email, password: password});
```

but how do I edit the users details once they're created? (ie: Change the password or the e-mail address?). I would think something like this:

```
this.af.auth.updateUser({email: email, password: password});
```

But there's no `updateUser` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have once faced this problem and have not got an angularfire2 answer yet.

Here is a native firebase way I get through this problem.

```
public auth: any;
constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: any) {
  this.auth = firebaseApp.auth();
}

reset(targetEmail: any) {
  this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(targetEmail);
}
```

**Note:**

It seems we could not change the password directly, only to send a password reset eamil to the target email address.

Comment: Pengyy how can I use script in **Angular 4**?
I have use the package **angularfire2** but its very difficult to use and is there any easy way to use **firebase** in my application?

Answer (score 7):

With AngularFire2 you just need to add "currentUser" to your path.

```
this.af.auth.currentUser.updateEmail(email)
.then(() => {
  ...
});
```

You will also need to reauthenticate the login prior to calling this as Firebase requires a fresh authentication to perform certain account functions such as deleting the account, changing the email or the password.

For the project I just implemented this on, I just included the login as part of the change password/email forms and then called "signInWithEmailAndPassword" just prior to the "updateEmail" call.

**To update the password just do the following:**

```
this.af.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password)
.then(() => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: The current way to do this would be `this.af.auth.currentUser.then(user => {user.updatePassword(password)});`